# Definition of args in macro return compilation warning

Tags: c, struct

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARGS \
    struct kk *k, \
    struct kk1 *k1 \


struct kk {
    int a;
    int b;
    int (*f)(ARGS);
};

struct kk1 {
    char a;
    char b;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct kk pp = {.a = 1};
    printf("ddmsgstsssssssr ___(%d)__\n", pp.a);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following warning when I build it with `gcc -o test test.c`:

```
test.c:6:9: warning: ‘struct kk1’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
  struct kk1 *k1 \
         ^
test.c:12:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘ARGS’
  int (*f)(ARGS);
           ^
test.c:6:9: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
  struct kk1 *k1 \
         ^
test.c:12:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘ARGS’
  int (*f)(ARGS);
           ^
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you using a macro? Do you like code that is unreadable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either move `struct kk1` before `struct kk`, or forward declare `struct kk1`. The latter one is more elegant, if you don't want to define the struct already.

```
#define ARGS \
    struct kk *k, \
    struct kk1 *k1 \

struct kk1; /* this changed */
struct kk {
    int a;
    int b;
    int (*f)(ARGS);
};

struct kk1 {
    char a;
    char b;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of `struct kk1` up so that it comes before `struct kk`. That is required as `struct kk` references `struct kk1`.

```
struct kk1 {
    char a;
    char b;
};

struct kk {
    int a;
    int b;
    int (*f)(ARGS);
};
```

Comment: It's not required if you use foward declarations, which is much more convenient.

Comment: Yes, that is another way to do it. But I don't see the point of typing more for a forward declaration in this simple example. It's just a matter of preference in this case.

Comment: It's likely a minimal example. As programs scale, you'll need a very structured approach, and forward declare everything. This seems like a magic rule, unless you're taught the benefit of forward declarations in the simple cases (i.e. the order of definition no longer matters).

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with forward declarations, compile with warnings:

```
warning: ISO C forbids forward parameter declarations
```

And change to:

```
#define ARGS \
    struct kk *k, \
    struct kk1 *k1

struct kk1 {
    char a;
    char b;
};

/* Now kk1 is visible inside kk */

struct kk {
    int a;
    int b;
    int (*f)(ARGS);
};
```

But there is no need to write such obfuscated code

```
int (*f)(struct kk *, struct kk1 *);
```

is more readable